# passing list to view

Tags: asp.net, list, view

I'm trying to pass a list from a controller to a view. I've checked the controller side with breakpoints and everything seems to be ok. problem is in the view. i get only the last element of the list for all positions in the list.

example

list in controller is : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

in view the list is : 5, 5, 5, 5, 5

controller code :

```
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            AdminController AC = new AdminController();
            List<ShowAllMessagesModel> SAMM = new List<ShowAllMessagesModel>();
            SAMM = AC.showAllMessages();
            ViewData["myList"] = SAMM;
            return PartialView();
        }
```

view code :

```
<%  var list = ViewData["myList"] as List<sms.Models.ShowAllMessagesModel>; %>
<%= list.Count %>
<% 
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.Count ; i++) 
    {
   %>
   <li>MsgId : <%= list.ElementAt(i).MessageId%> Sender : <%= list.ElementAt(i).Sender%></li>
   <% } %>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Use `List<ShowAllMessagesModel> SAMM = AC.showAllMessages();` - you don't need to create an instance, which is immediately forgotten.

Comment: didn't do anything..  the list get's passed it's the same size .. but on every position it's the last item of the list .. that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently you need to instantiate every element of the list otherwise it will insert the same element every time :)

```
List<var> examplelist = new List<var>();

for ( int i =0 ; i <=10 ; i++)
{
    var = new var();
    exampleList.Add(var);
}
```